# Sorting multidimensional JSON objects in python

Tags: python, json, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an object as such and want to sort it by time (line first, point second) in each dimension (simplified json):

```
[{
    "type":"point"
},
{
    "type":"line",
    "children": [
        {
            "type":"point"
        },
        {
            "type":"point"
        },
        {
            "type":"line"
        }
    ]

},
{
    "type":"point"     
}]
```

This **dimention could be deeper** and have much more points/lines within each other.

The **sorted output** would be something like this:

```
[{
    "type":"line",
    "children": [
        {
            "type":"line"
        },
        {
            "type":"point"
        },
        {
            "type":"point"
        }
    ]

},
{
    "type":"point"
},
{
    "type":"point"     
}]
```

Thanks

Comment: ...and? Where are you running into trouble? What have you tried? (And are you really doing this with JSON objects, or -- and I think this is more likely -- Python arrays and dictionaries...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to process this recursively:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def sortLinesPoints(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        if 'children' in data:
            sortLinesPoints(data['children'])
    else:
        for elem in data:
            sortLinesPoints(elem)
        data.sort(key=itemgetter('type'))
```

Comment: Awesome, it works, but how would i do this in reverse, so points come before lines just so i know? Thanks for an awesome answer.

Comment: @CezarisLT: add `reversed=True` to the `sort()` method.